# Access Query - Group by and Max

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been working on this for a few hours now and just can not figure it out.

How would I go about sorting this query by enco_id and only having the max of each clpr_id show up. for example:

[image: What my completed query looks like]

[image: What I want it to look like]

Here is my MSAccess Sql Code

```
SELECT dbo_Client.med_rec_no, dbo_Encounter.episode_number, dbo_client_program.enco_id, dbo_client_program.clpr_id, dbo_client_program.prle_id, dbo_PROGRAM_LEVEL.prle_name, dbo_Client.fname, dbo_Client.lname, dbo_DISCHARGE_STATUS.dist_name, DS2.dist_name
FROM (((((dbo_Client INNER JOIN dbo_Encounter ON dbo_Client.client_id = dbo_Encounter.client_id) INNER JOIN dbo_Episode_info ON dbo_Encounter.enco_id = dbo_Episode_info.enco_id) INNER JOIN dbo_DISCHARGE_STATUS ON dbo_Episode_info.dist_id = dbo_DISCHARGE_STATUS.dist_id) INNER JOIN dbo_client_program ON dbo_Encounter.enco_id = dbo_client_program.enco_id) INNER JOIN dbo_DISCHARGE_STATUS AS DS2 ON dbo_client_program.dist_id = DS2.dist_id) INNER JOIN dbo_PROGRAM_LEVEL ON dbo_client_program.prle_id = dbo_PROGRAM_LEVEL.prle_id;
```

Also here is what my query looks like

[image: My Access Query]

EDIT:

This is the code I am trying to use now and it still is not working

```
SELECT dbo_Client.client_id, dbo_Client.med_rec_no, dbo_Encounter.episode_number, dbo_Encounter.start_date, dbo_Encounter.end_date, dbo_client_program.clpr_id, dbo_client_program.enco_id, dbo_PROGRAM_LEVEL.prle_name, dbo_Client.fname, dbo_Client.lname, dbo_DISCHARGE_STATUS.dist_name, DS2.dist_name
FROM (((((dbo_Client INNER JOIN dbo_Encounter ON dbo_Client.client_id = dbo_Encounter.client_id) INNER JOIN dbo_Episode_info ON dbo_Encounter.enco_id = dbo_Episode_info.enco_id) INNER JOIN dbo_DISCHARGE_STATUS ON dbo_Episode_info.dist_id = dbo_DISCHARGE_STATUS.dist_id) INNER JOIN dbo_client_program ON dbo_Encounter.enco_id = dbo_client_program.enco_id) INNER JOIN dbo_DISCHARGE_STATUS AS DS2 ON dbo_client_program.dist_id = DS2.dist_id) INNER JOIN dbo_PROGRAM_LEVEL ON dbo_client_program.prle_id = dbo_PROGRAM_LEVEL.prle_id
WHERE dbo_client_program.clpr_id IN
(SELECT TOP 1 clpr_id FROM dbo_client_program as New
WHERE New.clpr_id = dbo_client_program.clpr_id
ORDER by dbo_client_program.clpr_id DESC) AND (dbo_DISCHARGE_STATUS.dist_name <> DS2.dist_name) AND dbo_Encounter.start_date > #1/1/2020# AND dbo_Encounter.end_date > #1/1/2020#
ORDER BY  dbo_Encounter.episode_number;
```

Comment: What is the problem with the SQL you posted?

Comment: It does not do what I want it to do.... I need to sort by enco_id and then take the max of clpr_id of the sorted enco_id.  I can not figure out the subquery to make it happen

Comment: Your question says "sorting this query by episode number and only having the max of each episode number show up" which doesn't really make sense nor agree with your comment. Data sample should be provided as text table, not image. Edit question. Use an aggregate query or nested TOP N.

Comment: Try building an aggregate query using dbo_client_program with Max(clpr_id) and grouping on enco_id. Then join that query to dbo_Encounter.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to figure all of this out,  I am watching many tutorials right now and still dont fully understand how to build an aggregate query.  I am very new to this language.

Comment: Here is what I am trying right now that is not working the way I want,   It actually appears to be doing the exact opposite.

Comment: Aggregate queries are simple to do using query designer. Result would be like `SELECT enco_id, Max(clpr_ID) AS MaxCLPR FROM dbo_client_program GROUP BY enco_id;`. Or do nested TOP N on dbo_client_program table without any joins to other tables. Just do this query to return top record for each enco_id. Then use this query in another to join to tables or other queries.

Comment: Hi again, I appriciate your help but you are talking so far above my head right now.  I dont have a clue what any of that means.  I am trying to read up on it but seriously I just need to fix one query and I will probably never use Access again.  Can you dumb it down for me please.  Thanks

Comment: in the designer, right click the data table area to the right of of the labels field, table, sort.  From the context menu that pops up select totals.  In the total row that now displays choose max for clpr_ID.  leave the rest at group by.  if that doesn't work choose first for some of those group bys.  Make sure not to forget the sort for enco_id.  This will work if there are no problems with the data in your base.

Answer (score 0):

As you are still understanding the aggregate queries my suggestion is:

1-Create a query where you group by all fields and max(clpr_id). Save this as "Query1"
  2-Create another query based on "Query1" and sort by "enco_id "